# Proof-verification: $A\times B \subset C \times D \Rightarrow A\subset C$ and$B \subset D$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I think I have a proof but Munkres' statement "assuming $A$ and $B$ are nonempty" is making me unsure. [EDIT to clarify: This statement is given twice, once without the "assuming nonempty" and once with.]

By contrapositive: I will show $A\not \subset C$ OR $B\not \subset D \Rightarrow A\times B \not \subset C \times D$. WLOG, suppose $A\not\subset C$. Pick $x\in A$ so that $x\notin C$, $y\in B$. Then $(x,y)\in A\times B$, but $(x,y)\notin C\times D$ since $x\notin C$.

P.S. Anyone know of a handy reference with solutions to Munkres' Topology exercises? For small questions like this one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To pick a $y\in B$ you must further assume $B$ is non-empty. If one of $A$ or $B$ is empty, then $A\times B$ is empty, and thus contained in $C\times D$ no matter what $C$ and $D$ are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof almost works, except for here:

> [...] so that $x \notin C, y \in B$

If the set $B$ is empty, then it won't be possible to find such a $y\in B$, and so we won't be able to form the tuple $\langle x,y \rangle$ or say anything about it.

In fact, if $A$ or $B$ is empty, then $A\times B = \varnothing$, in which case $A \times B$ is a subset of *every* set and the theorem doesn't hold.