# How to be rigorous?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question, self-learning

I am a computer science major currently self-studying mathematics.

Today I was studying topology and found out that I don't even know elementary facts like $(A \times B) \subset (C \times D)$ doesn't imply $A \subset B$ and $C \subset D%$.

I want to make my proof rigorous, but it is not easy. Do math majors also make mistakes like above? And if they don't, Can I be like them without undergraduate education in mathematics? How?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you meant, $(A \times B) \subset (C \times D)$ implies $A \subset C$ and $B \subset D%$, then I think that is true. Maybe that's what you meant? But as it stands, why should $A \subset B$ or $C \subset D$ ? In the statement $(A \times B) \subset (C \times D)$, $A$ and $B$ are "independent" and so are $C$ and $D$...

Comment: @AdamRubinson I thought so, but if A is empty, that is not true.

Comment: If $A$ is empty, what is not true? Please be more specific.

Comment: I meant that if $A$ is empty, then $C$ doesn't have to be the subset of $D$, even if $(A \times B) \subset (C \times D)$. (It is from Munkres, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1841952/proof-verification-a-times-b-subset-c-times-d-rightarrow-a-subset-c-andb)

Comment: Just to say:   If $S$ is some fixed set, then surely $S\times S^2$ is a subset of $S^2\times S$, as both of these are just $S^3$.

Comment: The key to being rigorous is to always keep the definitions in mind. Even then, math majors make mistakes. The example in your question is one nice candidate for making mistakes :) If $(A \times B)$ is non-empty, then $(A \times B) \subset (C \times D) \implies A \subset C, B \subset D$. But if only one of $A$ and $B$ is empty, then $(A \times B)$ is empty, and the assertion does not hold.

Comment: @lulu Sorry, I am confusing here. Let $a \in S$. does $(a, (a, a))$ treated equal to $((a, a), a)$?

Comment: @joy Thanks! I was trying to say that.

Comment: It's a question of what is meant by the notation.  Sets which are naturally isomorphic are often identified without a lot of fanfare.  Thus $S\times S^2$ is "the same" as $S^2\times S$ in a natural way, and both of them are "the same" as $S^3$.  If you meant something more specific, you should say so explicitly.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @corbusier I am a math major and I missed the point of your question which is in joy's comment, which is clearly correct. So there we go, yes everyone makes mistakes. The best way to make fewer mistakes is to ask questions, or to get your work looked at by the community. This is why the peer-review process is important...

Comment: @AdamRubinson Thanks! I think I just have to try harder.